# Displaying a Facebook newsfeed/timeline on a website

Tags: php, html, facebook, web-services

I have a client who wants their company's Facebook newsfeed/timeline to be displayed on their website. It's not a personal timeline/newsfeed, but an organisation's.

Everything I've read seems a few years old, but the upshot appears to be: Facebook wants to keep all its data on its own servers -- they don't want people exporting it, and people have been banned for trying. (As I say, this information was several years old.)

The closest current thing I've found is the [Activity Feed Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/), but that only registers other user's interactions with the site or a FB app.

Has anyone had any success exporting their public updates to an external website, or do I have to tell my client that it can't be done?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just in case you guys want to display a Facebook page's timeline feed, I found a tutorial that explains how to do it, step by step https://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/10/display-facebook-page-feed-on-wordpress-or-website.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

AFAIK, it is possible, in a way. The simplest solution, but not best for your situation could be the [Like Box plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/):

> The Like Box enables users to:
>
> See how many users already like this Page, and which of their friends like it too
>
> Read **recent posts** from the Page
>
> Like the Page with one click, without needing to visit the Page

Better solution: use their [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), however you can only read the data(as JSON), not have the stream exactly replicated on your client's website, don't expect to be able to apply the styles that facebook uses(i.e you won't be able to scrape it), you'll have to either replicate it, or create your own styles.

Now if the page is public and can be read by all, as in there are no privacy rules, then you can simply call the url with any valid access_token(can be app access_token also):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<clientpagename_OR_id>/feed
```

or

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<clientpagename_OR_id>/posts
```

depending on what exactly you need, try the [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to check that(and also see the kind of data being returned). When there are lots of posts, there will be pagination urls, which you'll be able to notice in the explorer too.

Incase the page is not public, you'll need an access_token with the read_stream permission, hence you'll need to create a [facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), of type website. Then get your client's page's admin to authorize the app, with `read_stream` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#extended_perms). After that you can call the urls with the access_token that you receive after authentication and can continue reading the stream.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<clientpagename_OR_id>/posts?access_token=thetoken
```

In this case use the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/), to simplify authentication and calling the graph api.

Important Links: [Authentication Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) , [Real-time-updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).

Good luck.

Edit: you do need an access token to access the feed or posts **connections**, but you do not necessarily need an access token to read the page object itself, as given in [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/).

Note from the doc:

> For connections that require an access token, you can use any valid access token if the page is public and not restricted. Connections on restricted pages require a user access token and are only visible to users who meet the restriction criteria (e.g. age) set on the page.

Comment: Real-time updates won't be useful at the moment, because it doesn't have a connection for posts yet, however i have given you the link for future reference

Comment: I've hunted around and I can't find a single "public" page that doesn't require an access token. I guess you need one, no matter what.

Comment: there is one page that i know of, which was recently mentioned in a question here. try this url in the [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=dominos%2Fposts) : `https://graph.facebook.com/dominos/posts` or just in the browser address bar. Also if you think you want to award me the bounty then you'll have to do it [manually](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty), incase the 24 hour period is over.

Comment: I have to wait few hours before it will let me.

Comment: yeah i checked the start time, no worries, but do try the dominos page, its public, i had tried it yesterday.

Comment: Oddly I still get an access token request for the Dominos site, btw.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10432/discussion-between-bool-dev-and-django-reinhardt)

Answer (score 7):

You can retrieve the organization's newsfeed using Facebook's Graph API. Timeline can't be retrieved via public API.

There is no plugin to do this. You would need to call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/home
```

which gives you a JSON response.

You then need to parse the JSON into a new layout on the organization's web page.

Confusingly, calling

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed
```

doesn't retrieve the newsfeed, but a user's wall posts, which may or may not be what you want.

[Here](http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2011/php/adding-a-facebook-news-status-feed-to-a-website/) is a tutorial that goes through the basics of setting up a newsfeed on a website with php.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to read the Facebook timeline RSS:

```
function FacebookFeed($pagename, $count, $postlength) {
$pageID = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids='.$pagename.'&fields=id');
$pageID = json_decode($pageID,true);
$pageID = $pageID[$pagename]['id'];

ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9');
$rssUrl = 'http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id='.$pageID;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($rssUrl);
$entry = $xml->channel->item;

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$description_original = $entry[$i]->description;
$description_striphtml = strip_tags($description_original);
$description = substr($description_striphtml, 0, $postlength);

$link = $entry[$i]->link;

$date_original = $entry[$i]->pubDate;
$date = date('d-m-Y, H:i', strtotime($date_original));

$FB_feed .= $description."&hellip;<br>";
$FB_feed .= "<small><a href='".$link."'>".$date."</a></small><br><br>";
}

return $FB_feed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done. First register the web site at facebook's developer page. Than you can use any suitable API for interacting with FB. Sometimes ago I used SpringSocial (since I was working tightly with Spring)... You can use FB's own api which is also very useful you can read the tutorial [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/)

Comment: I have looked through the API documentation and I can't see anything which would allow me to do what I need :(

Comment: There are a few wordpress plugins where you can just show your facebook page now after you add an access token. I helped develop this one. http://www.slickremix.com/downloads/feed-them-social-premium-extension/

Answer (score 1):

It can definitely be done.  You just need to get an access token through facebook and then you can access a JSON feed of posts through the facebook API.

You need to go to the facebook developer site and click on Apps at the top. Follow the steps to get an app secret and client ID.  Then just put them into the following URL and it will return your access token:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET

Step by step instructions here: http://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/access-token/

Answer (score 1):

This document details the steps to obtain the facebook access tokens and the using the tokens to fetch FB feeds.

**Example:**
A live example is available in

> https://newtonjoshua.com

**Introduction to Graph API:**
The Graph API is the primary way to get data in and out of Facebook's platform. It's a low-level HTTP-based API that you can use to query data, post new stories, manage ads, upload photos and a variety of other tasks that an app might need to do.

**FaceBook Apps:**

> https://developers.facebook.com

Create a Facebook app. You will get an `App_Id` and `App_Secret`

**Graph API Explorer:**

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/`{{App_Id}}`/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed&version=v2.8

You will get an `access_token` which is short lived. So this will be our `short_lived_access_token`.

note: while creating access token select all the fb fields that you require.This will give permission to the access token to fetch those fields.

**Access Token Extension:**

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=**{{App_Id}}**&client_secret=**{{App_Secret}}**&fb_exchange_token=**{{short-lived-access_token}}**

You will get an `access_token` with a validity of 2 months.

**Access Token Debugger:**

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken?q=**{{access_token}}**&version=v2.8

you can check check the details of the `access_token`.

**Facebook SDK for JavaScript:**
Include the below JavaScript in your HTML to asynchronously load the SDK into your page

```
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

**Graph API:**
Let's make an API call to get our FB id, profile pic, cover pic and feeds.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '{{App_Id }}',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.7'
    });
    FB.api(
        '/me',
        'GET', {
            fields: 'id,picture{url},cover,feed',
            access_token: {{access_token}}
        },
        function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
                console.error(response.error.message);
            }
            if (response.picture.data.url) {
                profilePic = response.picture.data.url;
            }
            if (response.cover.source) {
                coverPic = response.cover.source;
            }
            if (response.feed.data) {
        feeds = response.feed.data;
                feeds.forEach(function (feed) {
            // view each feed content
                });
            }
            if (response.feed.paging.next) {
                nextFeedPage = response.feed.paging.next;
        // a request to nextFeedPage will give the next set of feeds
            }

        }
    );
};
```

Use the Graph API Explorer to design your query that should be entered in the 'fields' (eg: 'id,picture{url},cover,feed')

Now you can fetch your Facebook data from Facebook Graph API using your access_token.

Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/

Note: Your `access_token` will expire in 2 months. Create a new access_token after that.